# Can't open Outfile error (NSIS 3.0.5) when using a specific strftime Format for !define /date "NOW"

Tags: file-io, compilation, nsis

I have following definition:  `!define /date NOW "%Y-%b-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
When creating the outfile as such: `OutFile "..\my_app_name_Setup-x64_${NOW}_Build_${__COUNTER__}.exe"`
compiles successful. However when i change the format to: `!define /date NOW "%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S"`  (Effectively changing the hyphens by colons for Hours, Minutes and Seconds) it no longer compiles successful.  (Compile error ´Can´t open Outfile at the very end).
Two (2) questions:

1. What causes this error?
2. How can i use my preferred strftime Format? (= with colons for HH:MM:SS)

Maybe Anders can shine a light on this ;)

Add2.  as per [https://nsis.sourceforge.io/mediawiki/index.php?title=Reference/!define&oldid=24774](http:////https://nsis.sourceforge.io/mediawiki/index.php?title=Reference/!define&oldid=24774) tmy formatting (`"%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S"` is correct.  (Might be depreciated(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colons are not legal in filenames on Windows. See [Naming Conventions: reserved characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions).

If you are compiling on POSIX it is theoretically legal but rather pointless since you cannot execute the installer without renaming it.

Comment: We definitely spend way too much time on UNIX machines (FreeBSD)...  Anyway, thnx Anders.